# What is the industry standard reference designator prefix for a PCB mount EMI shield

Tags: schematics

**Is there an industry standard electrical schematic reference designator prefix for a PCB mount EMI shield.  And if so, what is it?**

I am creating component libraries for my CAD tool.  I created a symbol for the TE Connectivity 2118726-2.
https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=2118726&DocType=Customer+Drawing&DocLang=English

The CAD tool requires that there be some sort of reference designator prefix for the symbol.  The tool doesn't care what it is, but if possible I would like to follow what is common in other libraries.

A diode is "D".  A resistor is "R".  A shield is probably not "S" (because that's a switch), but possibly "SH"?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no standard. SH would work. I might use MEC for "mechanical part".

Comment: I don't think I've seen one either.  When we need to provide a ground ring on the top layer of a PWB in order to provide provisions to mount  what we call an "EMI Hut", that is usually done with some instructions to the drafter laying out and routing the PWB.  I don't think I've seen a schematic symbol that goes along with the GND ring.

Comment: I'm a fan of using EMS (EM Shield) as the designator, but I second what the others said - there's no standard.